# Cambiar posición mensaje en Toast Android

Tags: java, android, mensajes, android-toast

Hola a todos de nuevo ando con una duda, quiero cambiarlo de horizontal a vertical el mensaje pero no puedo hacerlo, esta en toast.

Capture java

```
 void onShutterButtonPressContinuous() {
    isPaused = true;
    handler.stop();
    beepManager.playBeepSoundAndVibrate();
    if (lastResult != null) {
        handleOcrDecode(lastResult);
    } else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "No reconocio el numero", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, -1000);
        toast.show();
        resumeContinuousDecoding();
    }
}
```

Ya cambie todo de toast a lo que eh visto en tutoriales pero sin resultado no se si es algo de layout que no me deja que se cambie de posicion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Deseas que aparezca en la parte superior, centrado.
Si tu app está orientada a Android 11 (nivel de API 30) o superior, el uso de [.setGravity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#setGravity(int,%20int,%20int)) ya es obsoleto, por lo tanto, **realizar esto ya no funcionaría**:

```
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
```

**Ahora debes hacer uso de `.setMargin()` y la mejor opción para lograr lo que deseas es crear un `Toast` Personalizado.**

Crea un layout `custom_toast.xml` :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_toast"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bakground_custom_toast">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textToShow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hai!"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

y un método para mostrar el layout:

```
public static void showCustomToast(Context ctx, String msg, int duration, int position){
    try{
        if(!"".equals(msg)){
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, null);
            TextView text = layout.findViewById(R.id.textToShow);
            text.setText(msg);
            Toast toast = new Toast(ctx.getApplicationContext());
            switch(position){
                case TOAST_TOP:
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER,0,200);
                    break;
                case TOAST_CENTER:
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                    break;
                case TOAST_BOTTOM:
                default:
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 200);
                    break;
            }
            toast.setMargin(0.01f, 0.01f);
            toast.setDuration(duration);
            toast.setView(layout);
            toast.show();
        }
    }catch(IllegalStateException ise){
        Log.e(TAG, "showCustomToast(), " + ise.getMessage());
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "showCustomToast(), " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

de esta forma llamas el método para generar tu `Toast` personalizado

```
  showCustomToast(getApplicationContext(), "No reconocio el numero", Toast.LENGTH_LONG, TOAST_TOP);
```

[image: Jorgesys Custom Toast with position]

Comment: Jorgesys ando intentando con tu metodo pero no me da resultados, alguna otra opcion aparte del que me comentaste te lo agradeceria bastante

Comment: Debe funcionar similar a como se muestra en la imqgen, que error se obtiene la tratar de mostrar el toast?

Comment: Jorgesys no muestra nada, alguna forma de rotar el toast a 180 grados?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con:

```
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
```

Esto hará que aparezca arriba y la izquierda. Pero puedes cambiar el resto de valores.

Recuerda que el setGravity acepta 3 parámetros (gravity, posición X, posición Y)

Suerte.